# combining two HTML codes in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jupyter-notebook

I have the following two scripts written in python.I run them in IPython notebook. When i call Textbox1 and Texbox2 in different cells, I see both the boxes. However, i want these textboxes to be seen in an external HTML file. How do i combine and send this to HTML through python.

```
 Textbox1="""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function retrieve(id) {
    var txtbox = document.getElementById(id);
    value = txtbox.value;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" size="4" style="width: 100px;" value="Enter Email"        name="txt" id="txt"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="retrieve('txt');"/

    </body>
    </html>
    """`


 Textbox2="""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function retrieve(id) {
    var txtbox = document.getElementById(id);
    value = txtbox.value;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" size="4" style="width: 100px;" value="Enter Password"        name="txt" id="txt"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="retrieve('txt');"/

    </body>
    </html>
    """`
```

I use `from IPython.display import HTML` to see HTML output in the notebook

Comment: Do you want to simply save this html to an externel file? Try `with open(mypath, 'a) as f: print(Textbox1, file=f)`. Or is there more to your question then simply writing to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two boxes in one HTML string first, something like (will need formatting I guess):

```
Textbox1and2="""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function retrieve(id) {
var txtbox = document.getElementById(id);
value = txtbox.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" size="4" style="width: 100px;" value="Enter Email" name="txt" id="txt"></input>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="retrieve('txt');"/
<input type="text" size="4" style="width: 100px;" value="Enter Password" name="txt" id="txt"></input>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="retrieve('txt');"/

</body>
</html>
"""
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it, modify it further,print it with HTML() or save to a file, etc.